# \url command puts an "M" before the URL

Tags: url

I hope that this question hasn't been asked yet, but I could not find anything about it:
If I use the command \url for my urls, the output has an "M" before the hyperlink (e.g.: `Mhttps://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask` as an Output, if I note `\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask}`) The linkage works, but since I will print the document as my master thesis, I need to delete the `M`. What can I do?
I normally use the package `hyperref`, but if I use the `url`-package, I have the same problem.

Comment: Please share a MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: Your code works fine, so there's something you're doing wrong

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by removing a package, as noted in an "answer", now removed.  In the absence of an example, it isn't possible to be more specific.